# Exclude keyword in Style Configurator profile

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to type a keyword into "User-defined keywords" box such that instead of including it in special highlighting, its explicitly excluded instead?  I'm working with python3 and the "Default keywords" list for python in the Style Configurator includes "print". However this looks weird to me since "print" is now a builtin function instead of a keyword.  I would like it to be unhighlighted but you cant delete from the "Default keywords" box.

Ideally looking for a solution that uses user-define settings so I don't have to tamper with the default settings but i'll take the latter as well.

I've tried "~print", "^print", and "-print" already.